# Windows Defender command line scan fails

Tags: command-line, windows-defender

When I run `MpCmdRun.exe -Scan -ScanType 1` (or 2) it echos "Scan starting..." and INSTANTLY throws me back to the command prompt.  This works fine on other machines, just not the one in question.

[image]

When I check `c:\windows\temp\mpcmdrun.log` the last entry looks like this:

[image]

> ERROR: MpScan(dwOptions=16385) Completion Failed 80508018

Google only has 5 results that include the exact error ID and none of them have been useful.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following works (I tested it and the Quick Scan properly completed.

I opened cmd.exe with Run as Administrator (important).

I navigated to c:\Program Files\Windows Defender.

I ran:  mpcmdrun.exe -scan -1

"Scan starting ...".

"Scan finished".

Try as suggested (it works) and then adjust from there.

From:

[Defender Scan from Command Line](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/command-line-arguments-microsoft-defender-antivirus)

Here's an example:

> Console
>
> MpCmdRun.exe -Scan -ScanType 2 TABLE 1 Command    Description
> -? or -h  Displays all available options for this tool
> -Scan [-ScanType [0|1|2|3]] [-File  [-DisableRemediation] [-BootSectorScan] [-CpuThrottling]] [-Timeout ] [-Cancel]    Scans
> for malicious software. Values for ScanType are: 0 Default, according
> to your configuration, -1 Quick scan, -2 Full scan, -3 File and
> directory custom scan. CpuThrottling will honor the configured CPU
> throttling from policy

Comment: This is exactly what I did, with the exception of the shortcut for `-ScanType 1`.  It does not work on this machine.

Comment: Maybe try Repairing your machine  (Windows 10 Media creation link) and repair it. It works as expected on a working machine

Comment: I'd rather wait and see if anyone actually knows anything about the error mentioned or how to fix it.

Comment: No error here - that is why I suggest repairing.